# Is it possible to convert a reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas into a SVG?

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

I am trying to get a svg and change it's color into a vertical gradient:

```
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor

def get_svg_str():
    origin_color, destination_color = HexColor(0xFF0000), HexColor(0xFFFF00)
    with open("given.svg") as fp:
         img_content = fp.read()
         buffer = io.BytesIO(img_content.encode())
         c = Canvas(buffer)
         c.linearGradient(0 * mm, 0 * mm, 0, 150 * mm, (origin_color, destination_color))
         return c.toSVGString() ???? is there a way to do so ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I used javascript to get my task done - seems like it's an issue with reportlab